# hasattr() throws AttributeError

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to check if some xml in a django app has certain elements/nodes and if not just to skip that code block. I'm checking for the elements existance using hasattr(), which should return false if the element doesn't exist:

`if hasattr(product.ItemAttributes, 'ListPrice')  \ and hasattr(product.Offers.Offer.OfferListing, 'PercentageSaved') \
                            and hasattr(product.LargeImage, 'URL'):`

Except in my case it's throwing an attribute error:
`AttributeError at /update_products/
no such child: {http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}LargeImage`

I don't understand why it's throwing an error instead of just returning false and letting me skip the code block?

Comment: Perhaps one of `product.ItemAttributes`, `product.Offers.Offer.OfferListing`, `product.LargeImage` does not exist? Most likely `product.LargeImage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is complaining about `LargeImage`. That's being caused by this expression: `product.LargeImage`. You might want to check for that first, or even better, put this in a `try/except` block.

Comment: ah I didn't realise hasattr was dependant on parent attributes existing. I was just typing that your answer solved my question but then gave me a new problem of knowing if the target element exists without having to check to see if it's parent exists. However your updated answer with regards to the `try/except` block I think is the way to go, thanks!

Comment: @KingFu `hasattr` is not dependent on parent attributes existing. This error would occur without any calls to `hasattr` whatsoever. The issue is that you have an expression which attempts to refer to a non-existent attribute.

Comment: I see, I was basically trying to pass a non existent object. Thanks for your additional comment to clear that up for me